# Как задать связь 1:m и 1:1 (один ко многим, один к одному) flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть некоторая ER диаграмма. [image: ERD]

Здесь много связей `один ко многим`, например, между `Agents` и `Offers`. А между `Realties` и `Flat` изображена 1:m, но должна быть 1:1.

Я попробовал сделать так для 1:m

```
class Offer(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  agent = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('agent.id'))
  client = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('client.id'))
  realty = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('realty.id'))
  price = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

class Agent(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  middle_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  rate = db.Column(db.Float, default=45.)
  offers = db.relationship('Offer', backref='agent', lazy='dynamic') # 1:m Agent -> Offers
```

И так для 1:1

```
class Flat(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  city = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  street = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  house_num = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  flat_num = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
  longitude = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
  latitude = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
  area = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
  rooms = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  realty = db.relationship('Realty', backref='flat', uselist=False)  # 1:1 Flat <-> Realty

class Realty(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  flat = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('flat.id'))
  parcel = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('parcel.id'))
  house = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('house.id'))
  offers = db.relationship('Offer', backref='realty', lazy='dynamic')  # 1:m Realty -> Offers
```

Правильно ли задаются связи? Потому, что с readthedocs по flask-slqaclhemy я не понял, т.к. без схемы в первый раз трудно, а некоторые аргументы типа backref PyCharm не подсвечивает и я думаю, что это ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, правильный вариант следующий:
Если есть связь 1:m, то в таблице где `1` мы оставляет `<название поля(любое)> = db.relationship(<Название таблицы m>, backref=<уникальное название для этой связи>)`. `backref` обязательно должен быть уникальным, иначе возникнет ошибка, что такая связь уже существует. Т.е. если у вас, например, есть модель `User` и она связывается с таблицами `Posts` и `Followers`, то `backref` будет не `user`, а `user_posts` и `user_followers` к примеру. В таблице со связью `m` мы задаём `db.Column(<тип поля id со связью 1>, db.ForeignKey('user'))`, значение foreignkey равно названию сущности. Если мы хотим задать связь 1:1, то в relationship ещё одним аргументом ставим `uselist=False`.

Comment: Логичней указывать связь в классе с внешним ключом, то есть для m:1. Тогда и с уникальностью будет меньше проблем. В таблице Posts будет user=rel(users, backref=posts), а в Followers будет user=rel(users, backref=followers). Что соответсвенно позволит для User-а получить и сообщения posts, и подписчиков followers.

Comment: @Lecron кстати говоря, дельное замечание. Т.е. можно эту relationship в любом из классов задавать, которые имеют отношения?